# How to make the two horizontally positioned images closer to each other?

Tags: beamer, graphics, presentations, slideshow

I have two images located horizontally in a presentation slide, as below:-

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]

\minipage{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Image001.png}
\caption{abcd}
\endminipage\hfill

\minipage{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Image002.png}
\caption{efgh}
\endminipage

\end{figure}
```

[image]

However, the two images are far away from each other. How can I modify the code such that the images would be closer?

Many thanks!

Comment: Remove `\hfill` if you don't want additional space between the images and don't leave an empty line.

Comment: Off-topic: floating specifier like `[!htb]` don't make sense in a documentclass without floating mechanism.

Comment: I would use the following syntax for minipages:  `\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{efgh}
\end{minipage}`

Comment: Please use `\hfil` instead of `\hfill`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @samcarter said in her comment, but also add `\centering` to code if you are using `article` document class. with `latex` syntax your code should be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{abcd}
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{efgh}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Now I recognise that you are interested in a solution for the `beamer` documentclass. There you don't need to load `graphicx` as well as not using `centering`, the `figure` environment is centred by default:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}% no option, in beamer figure is not float
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{abcd}
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{efgh}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beamer centers figures by default. In fact the `figure` environment does little else than centering ...

Comment: you are right, i overlooked that the code should be for beamer (i consider article, as you can see). will be corrected asap.

Comment: Don't worry, the only clue that this about beamer is the blue headline in the image - very easy to overlook!

Comment: Thanks. And I have also used `\hspace{1em}` to replace `\hfil`. That gives me more flexibility in adjusting the distance.

Comment: @yeh, if op would provide mwe,  than i would be on right track from beginning. thank you very much for the note.